In React native, I'm facing the below error
Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerScreenCaptureObserver from pid=4161, uid=10197 requires android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE, js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I tried,creating a new project too, but after installing the required dependencies, get popped up with the same error.
